Is it always possible to draw a Tensor Network Diagram for a given Expression?
Background: I'm learning about Tensor Network Diagrams (TND) (see e.g. here https://quantumghent.github.io/TensorTutorials/2-TensorNetworks/TensorNetworks.html) and tensor operations in general. I came across the following expression for which I can't draw a satisfying TND. Now I wonder whether I do something wrong or whether TND simply can't express all ways to contract a tensor. Here's the example:
Question: Let $a= (a_i), b= (b_j), c= (c_k)$ be some vectors and $A=A_{i,j}, B=B_{i,k}, C=C_{j,k}$ be some matrices with entries in $\Bbb{R}$. Then how does the TND for
$$\sum_{i,j,k} a_i b_j c_k A_{i,j} B_{i,k}C_{j,k}$$
look?
Aside: I can recognize $(a_ib_jc_k)_{i,j,k}$ as an outer product of the three vectors. I imagine it as a cube. The TND would we a node with 3 arms sticking out. Then the matrix $A$ is "dotted" (Frobenius inner product) onto all the $(a_ib_j)$ matrices living in the cube $(a_ib_jc_k)_{i,j,k}$. For $B, C$ in a similar way, just "rotated". It's hard to describe but I was trying to get some intuition. The TND for each matrix would have 2 arms. Now I can't connect the 3 + 3*2 arms such that none is sticking out. Thanks in advance.

Unless tensor networks have started allowing hypergraphs, so that edges can connect between more than two objects, that's not a valid tensor network expression. Remember each index is associated with a half edge protruding off of one of your objects. If it appears twice, that means there are two half edges that need to meet to form a full edge. Indices should not be able to appear three or more times.
If you want to make that a valid expression, you'll need to extend tensor networks to allow for three edges meeting at a point that is not another tensor.
Where does that expression come from?
